# Does apple provides any API or something to access the camera, like facetime?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to ask a question about the apple API. Does apple provide some APIs for the developer to access the Facetime function, just like the ABPerson can access the address book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of camera access API's, including for the front camera, in the AVFoundation framework.